Can PIL.Image.thumbnail INCREASE an Images size?
I am using PIL.Image.thumbnail() to resize images whilst maintaining aspect ratio.
However I have noticed a rather annoying behaviour.
If the input image is already less than the provided WIDTH x LENGTH it doesn't appear to modify the image.
So in the below example:
image = Image.open(inputImage)   # This is a filepath
image.thumbnail((290,290))
image.save(outputImage)          # This is also a filepath :O

If the 'inputImage' points to an image already smaller than 290 x 290 the image saved to outputImage is identical in size.
So my question is: Does Image.thumbnail INCREASE an images size to match the provided size? Or is it limited to REDUCING an Images size?
Is there an input I'm missing here for my intended use of Universally resizing an image to 290x290 regardless of current size (larger or smaller)?
I haven't been able to find any information regarding this online. If I need to use Image.resize and calculate the aspect ratio of each image manually, I'll do it. I just wanted to ask first :)

This might help, What is the difference between Image.resize and Image.thumbnail in Pillow-Python

@Nesi This is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers for the link
